# A margin-right of unkown origins

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table (a tracklist) that i want to center right under the album cover and the title, the problem is that there's this huge margin to the right that i've never specified and only discovered using chrome's inspection tool, i'm trying to figure out the cause of this....but i need a bit of help with that. if someone could point out the cause of this or give any tips on the issue i would be truly grateful. thank you.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fdfcfa;
}

.body-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.navbar a{
    color: #FBFBFB;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 3.5em; 
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
;
    text-align: center;
}

#logo {
    width: 11%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container-ish {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
}

.note {    
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.container-ish p{
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

.record {
    padding-top: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.record img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
}

.record .text{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.record .text h2, h3, h4 {
    color: #6b6b6b;
}

.record .text h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

.record .text h2 {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.record .text h3 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.record .text h4 {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.tracklist {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

table {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1.18em;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#footnote {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.no, .duration {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #262626;
}

.footer{
    background-color: #1c2120;
    color: whitesmoke;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="body-container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="https://www.shawnjamesmusic.com/"><img id="logo" src="img/shawn+james+-+logo+-+sept+2018+01+REVERSE.png"></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="container">
                <div class="record">
                    <div class="container-ish">
                        <img src="img/Shawn+James+-+The+Dark+&+The+Light+Artwork+(High+Res).jpg" alt="artwork of the album The Dark & The Light">
                    </div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <h1>The Dark & The Light</h1>
                        <h2>Singer/Songwriter . 2019</h2>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="tracklist">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">1.</td>
                                <td class="title">Orpheus</td>
                                <td class="duration">3:58</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">2.</td>
                                <td class="title">Love Will Find a Way I</td>
                                <td class="duration">3:22</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">3.</td>
                                <td class="title">Love Will Find a Way II</td>
                                <td class="duration">3:06</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">4.</td>
                                <td class="title">There It Is</td>
                                <td class="duration">3:14</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">5.</td>
                                <td class="title">The Weak End</td>
                                <td class="duration">5:32</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">6.</td>
                                <td class="title">Burn the Witch</td>
                                <td class="duration">4:08</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">7.</td>
                                <td class="title">Haunted</td>
                                <td class="duration">4:18</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">8.</td>
                                <td class="title">The Curse of the Fold</td>
                                <td class="duration">5:19</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">9.</td>
                                <td class="title">Chicago</td>
                                <td class="duration">4:32</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no">10.</td>
                                <td class="title">When I'm Gone</td>
                                <td class="duration">3:50</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text" id="footnote">
                        <h3>10 songs, 41 minutes</h3>
                        <h4>March 22, 2019</h4>
                        <h4>&copy; 2019 Parts + Labor Records</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="footer-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: you give `width: 80%;` to **table** change to `width:100%`

Comment: Or `margin: 0 auto;` to table

Comment: Please try this @Ashmoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given your table a width of 80% because of which you see a a huge margin which is equal to the remaining 20% of width. In such cases if you want to center the element best way is to give a margin: 0px auto;

```
 table {
        width: 80%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the width.
Try this:

```
.tracklist
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: rgb(222,222,222);
width:800px;
}
```